# Java - Changing text size using canvas?

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am trying to change the size of the text I am drawing to my canvas. I have searched all the properties that the canvas method holds, but there are no options for text size.

```
canvas.drawText("TESTTT", 200, 200, colorCyan);
```

[image]

Obviously the text is way too small and the font is ugly :( What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set size to the paint object

```
 colorCyan.setTextSize(40f); // takes a float as the param
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setTextSize(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setTextSize%28float%29)

> public void setTextSize (float textSize)
>
> Added in API level 1 Set the paint's text size. This value must be > 0
>
> Parameters textSize   set the paint's text size.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't search too much ;)

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setTextSize(...
```

before drawing if.

Comment: I guess I didnt, I didnt even think of looking in paint, just saw that as my colour :P